# .NET Core Dependency Injection - Resolve implementations and IEnumerable of interface

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have an interface `IMyType` with several implementations `SomeMyType`, `OtherMyType`.

I want to use both the concrete types, as well as an IEnumerable of all types that implement the `IMyType` interface.

These could be the declarations in a service.

```cs
private readonly IEnumerable<IMyType> instances;
private readonly SomeMyType someType;
private readonly OtherMyType otherType;
```

One way to make this work is by using the following extension:

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddMyType<T>(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    where T : class, IMyType =>
    serviceCollection
        .AddSingleton(typeof(IMyType), typeof(T))
        .AddSingleton(typeof(T));
```

This adds a singleton for both the concrete type and the interface.

Is this a good way to configure the dependencies?

Are there other ways to improve the solution? I am thinking if this will create two instances of T, or if the framework tries to resolve the second singleton with the first T.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly ? LEt's imagine your IEnumerable is a list.
What do you expect to be present in the the list when you want to "Inject" you `List<IMyType>` ?

Comment: I expect all implementations of `IMyType` to be in the list. I want to run a method on all of them, where I don't care what type they have. I also want to run specific methods on specific types.

Comment: And I assume your list ischanging often or is very large ? Otherwise you could create a dedicated class/service that actually provides this List, and this provider class that itself has as dependency all the possible implementations (SomeMyType, OtherMyType) and does the job of creating the list.

Comment: No it's static and fairly small. I am basically just looking for a concise way of retrieving all instances of type T which are in the service collection, ideally without having to implement any additional provider.

Comment: maybe have a look at autofac or ninject, some more capable DI libs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register the class and when registering the interface, use the delegate factory to get the registered class.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddMyType<T>(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    where T : class, IMyType =>
    serviceCollection
        .AddSingleton<T>();
        .AddSingleton<IMyType>(sp => sp.GetService<T>());
```

Which would be used like

```
services.AddMyType<SomeMyType>();
services.AddMyType<OtherMyType>();
```

For resolving your services in this scenario, in order to get all the registered `IMyType`, inject `IEnumerable<IMyType>`

```
private readonly IEnumerable<IMyType> instances;

public MyClass(IEnumerable<IMyType> instances) {
    this.instances = instances;

    //...
}
```

The concrete types, having also been registered can be explicitly injected as needed as well

```
private readonly SomeMyType someType;

public MyClass(SomeMyType someType) {
    this.someType = someType;

    //...
}
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that in my code there would be 2 separate instances but in yours it retrieves the same one?

Comment: @AndreasVolkmann Yes. In your version there would be two separate instances. In mine there is only one for the provided concrete type.